# Generating signed APK, produces Remaining DexItemBasedString, android?

Tags: android, apk

When I am generating a signed APK, android studio gives me this error "Remaining DexItemBasedString" . Unable to find anything related to it on web.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Multidex? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @TonyL multidex is enabled . already

Comment: I'm guessing you have R8 turned on? I'm seeing this issue with R8.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different activities for different build variants, I think R8 is trying to be sure that activity exist when you start activity with class name:

```
Intent intent= null;
try {
    intent = new Intent(getContext(), Class.forName(“com.yourapp.TestActivity”));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
startActivity(intent);
```

If your activity is not exist in your release variant for example, maybe you can set your activity name from BuildConfig for each build seperately.